# Gitlab-CI clone private repo from setup.py with token instead of ssh keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab-ci

I have a Python project which I want to build and test with gitlab-ci.

In my setup.py file I have a few dependencies that can currently be downloaded using SSH keys.

```
[setup.py]
...
install_requires=[
    "test1 @ git+ssh://git@ssh.git.xxxx.de/path/to/repo/test1.git@1.1.0#egg=test1",
    "test2 @ git+ssh://git@ssh.git.xxxx.de/path/to/repo/test2.git@1.0.2#egg=test2",
],
```

Despite this configuration, can I use the "CI_JOB_TOKEN" in gitlab-ci pipeline to access these resources?

```
 echo -e "machine gitlab.com\nlogin gitlab-ci-token\npassword ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
```

Or do I inevitably have to store an additional secret variable with the ssh private key in gitlab-ci and add this key for each stage in "before_script"?

```
[gitlab-ci.yml]
...
before_script:
-  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
-  ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

Is there any advantage to using ssh-keys instead of https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [GitLab CI/CD docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#dependent-repositories):

> The Job environment variable `CI_JOB_TOKEN` can be used to authenticate any clones of dependent repositories.

As mentioned above, using **`CI_JOB_TOKEN`** does not give pipelines write access to dependent repositories. It can just be used for **clone/download** dependent repositories.
On the other side, using **SSH private key** gives more permissions to your pipeline.
There are other ways to access dependent repositories. You can access the repositories you need by defining [Deploy Tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) or [Deploy Keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/) for them.